# Scala: import not required to use immutable.Map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am learning Scala here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/iRJ8VOw7TySZ4KQ5qlWkdw.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet
// import scala.collection.immutable.Map // import not required to use immutable.Map

val m = Map((1 -> "a"), (2 -> "bb"))

val r = m.filter(_._1 > 1)

r // Map(2 -> bb): scala.collection.immutable.Map

println(r)
```

In the above codes, `r` is of type `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, even if `scala.collection.immutable.Map` not imported but `scala.collection.mutable` imported.

if import `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and `scala.collection.mutable._`, `r` is `immutable.Map`. if `import scala.collection.mutable._`, `r` is `mutable.Map`.

I am a little confused. Anyone can help explain it? Thanks

Comment: For those who don't want to re-google it: link to [Import clauses](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#import-clauses) in the Spec. I don't see where it tells me that `collection.mutable._` does not conflict with `collection.immutable.Map`. Shouldn't both import `Map`? Good question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are like five different questions in here, let's deal with them one by one.

---

**Why `import collection.mutable` seemingly does nothing?**

If we omit the unnecessary details from your code snippet, we obtain:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val r = Map(2 -> 3)
```

You asked why `r` is still `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

First, notice that

```
import scala.collection.mutable
```

is not the same as

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
```

The latter is a wildcard import (which would import mutable Map on demand), whereas the former only imports the symbol `mutable`. Therefore, in your code, only the symbol `mutable` is made available, but this does not influence the meaning of `Map` in any way.

---

**Where does the `scala.collection.immutable.Map` come from even if nothing is imported?**

The `Predef` is always imported implicitly (unless you deactivate it with a compiler flag). There is a type alias definition

```
type Map[A, +B] = collection.immutable.Map[A, B]
```

in [Predef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/Predef$.html#Map[A,+B]=scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B]), and there is also the direct shortcut to the companion object of `immutable.Map`:

```
val Map: collection.immutable.Map.type
```

which allows you to construct maps using the `Map(...)`-syntax without `new`-keyword.

---

**Why does `import collection.immutable.Map` take precedence over `import collection.mutable._`?**

The [specification states about the precedence of imports](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html):

> 1. Definitions and declarations that are local, inherited, or made available by a package clause in the same compilation unit where the definition occurs have highest precedence.
> 2. Explicit imports have next highest precedence.
> 3. Wildcard imports have next highest precedence.
> 4. Definitions made available by a package clause not in the compilation unit where the definition occurs have lowest precedence.

Therefore, because of points 2 and 3, an explicit import

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

has precedence over the wildcard import

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
```

---

**Why `import collection.mutable._` makes `Map` mutable?**

Now, one last thing is left to clarify: why does the `mutable._` wildcard import take precedence over the definition in `Predef`? Here is a short example that demonstrates it:

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
val m = Map()
println(m.getClass)
```

The output is (maybe somewhat surprisingly):

```
class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
```

The specification seems to be a bit vague on this point, at least I could not find where it says that ordinary wildcard imports overshadow the definitions in Predef. However, [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/09-top-level-definitions.html) it says:

> Every compilation unit implicitly imports the following packages, in the given order:
>
> - the package java.lang,
> - the package scala, and
> - the object scala.Predef, unless there is an explicit top-level import that references scala.Predef.
>
> Members of a later import in that order hide members of an earlier import.

I think the last sentence also covers the imports that come after `scala.Predef` that is, also the explicit wildcard imports. This is probably why `import scala.collection.mutable._` overshadows the definitions in `Predef`.

---

**What's going on in the REPL?**

When you are experimenting with imports, you must keep in mind that the REPL evaluates every line as if it were in a new nested block. This means that, for example, the script

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.immutable._
Map()
```

will result in

```
error: reference to Map is ambiguous
```

But if you type the same lines in a REPL one by one, then no error will occur, and you will get an immutable `Map`. This is because in the REPL, the above lines are interpreted as

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
{
  import scala.collection.immutable._
  {
    Map()
  }
}
```

so that the last import takes precedence. I'm not sure how Scastie handles it, probably it's the same there, so it is one additional complication that you have to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `Map` is not imported from `scale.collection.mutable` because there is a problem with your `import` statement.

Change

```
import scala.collection.mutable
```

to

```
import scala.collection.mutable._
```

or

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

and `Map` will be `mutable.Map`.

When you import both `scale.collection.immutable.Map` and `scala.collection.mutable._` the `immutable` `Map` wins because it is a more specific. So the most specific `import` wins and in the case of a tie you will get a compiler error.

Comment: `scala.collection.mutable` **is** imported. After it is imported you can use the symbol `mutable` without further qualification, e.g. `mutable.Map` instead of `scala.collection.mutable.Map`. And no, *"in the case of a tie"* the last import does not apply automatically, instead it produces `error: reference to Map is ambiguous`. It could be that the last import *appears* to win in REPL when used without paste-mode, because it essentially opens a new block for each line. But that's REPL-specific, it's not a property of the language itself.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks for the corrections, I have updated the answer to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default a Map in Scala is immutable.
You don´t import mutable.Map, so it is still immutable.
If you import it like this it should work:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
```

> if import scala.collection.immutable.Map and
>   scala.collection.mutable.*, r is immutable.Map. if import
>   scala.collection.mutable.*, r is mutable.Map.

The most qualified import statement wins.

Comment: What is "it" that should work? The OP gives three different ways to import different variants of `Map`, and asks why one or the other variant of `Map` turns out to be imported. Your answer does not explain all those different cases.

Answer (score 0):

By **default** Scala gives us **immutable Map**. There are **two ways** to create **mutable Map**:

```
**1.** Use import statement - *scala.collection.mutable._* to bring mutable map it into scope 
**2.** Specify the full path to *scala.collection.mutable.Map*
```

With the import "**import scala.collection.mutable._**", you are importing the all the mutable collection available **along with mutable map**.

If you are adding  **scala.collection.immutable.Map** along with **scala.collection.mutable._**, you are **telling the scala compiler to use all mutable collection, but in case of Map, use immutable.**

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr** use `import scala.collection.mutable.Map`

---

This is because `m` is an instance of `scala.collection.immutable.Map` (the default behavior). Similar behavior in java everything in `java.lang` package is implicitly imported.

You imported the package immutable, this does not automatically bring into scope `scala.collection.immutable.Map` to hide `scala.collection.mutable.Map`
For this you should `import scala.collection.mutable.Map`

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val m = Map((1 -> "a"), (2 -> "bb"))
println(m.getClass)  // class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2

val mutableMap = mutable.Map((1->"A"), (2->"BB"))
println(mutableMap.getClass) // class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
```

Alternatively

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
val m = Map((1 -> "a"), (2 -> "bb"))
println(m.getClass)  // class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
```